# How do I read the terse outout of stat?

Tags: filesystems, stat

There are no clues given about how to interpret the results of running the stat command with terse output.

```
[root@kvm devicemapper]# stat -t data 
data 107374182400 3887728 8180 0 0 fd01 559688 1 0 0 1633555816 1610128779 1610128779 0 4096
```

What am I looking at here? I recognize some of these values. There's no way to map some of these values to whatever property they represent because of the duplicates.

```
stat --version
stat (GNU coreutils) 8.22
```

*UPDATE*: looks like the coreutils developers fixed this issue in a later version of by adding the actual, system-dependent format string to the `--help` usage documentation. See `stat --help` output for the equivalent terse format https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/ebf2c4dcc687c9f057a8a22674fd984aa929012e/src/stat.c#L1792

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting [the code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/338446102698fa513ee399345811cb91827d05e5/src/stat.c#L1290) for coreutils 8.22, it looks like the terse equivalent printf format on my system is (which is not selinux enabled):

```
[root@kvm devicemapper]# stat -t data 
data 107374182400 3887728 8180 0 0 fd01 559688 1 0 0 1633555816 1610128779 1610128779 0 4096
[root@kvm devicemapper]# stat --printf="%n %s %b %f %u %g %D %i %h %t %T %X %Y %Z %W %o\n" data 
data 107374182400 3887728 8180 0 0 fd01 559688 1 0 0 1633555816 1610128779 1610128779 0 4096
```

(In version 8.22) That's:

```
%n %s %b %f %u %g %D %i %h %t %T %X %Y %Z %W %o

%n file name
%s total size, in bytes
%b number of blocks allocated
%f raw mode in hex
%u user ID of owner
%g group ID of owner
%D device number in hex
%i inode number
%h number of hard links
%t major device type in hex, for character/block device special files
%T minor device type in hex, for character/block device special files
%X time of last access, seconds since Epoch
%Y time of last modification, seconds since Epoch
%Z time of last change, seconds since Epoch
%W time of file birth, seconds since Epoch; 0 if unknown
%o optimal I/O transfer size hint
```

Assuming you have a later version of `stat`, running `stat --help` will include the equivalent format for terse.

Comment: The [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/coreutils/stat.1.en.html) also includes this information (" --terse is equivalent to the following FORMAT").

Comment: No, the man page does not include the terse format for my version, 8.22. As you can see, version 8.30 was updated to include the format and the format is not the same as 8.22. So, they updated the man page but there's a subtle difference in the format. The format is system dependent, because from the code you can see they change formats if your system is selinux enabled. Assuming you have a late version of stat, `stat --help` will show you the correct format for your system.